# Java, brackets placement issue {}

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment and I have everything done, but my if and else statements are both being executed. If I were to add the brackets where I believe they should go, I get an error about the 'else' statement having no 'if' tied to it.

If my 'if' statement doesnt execute, it will execute the 'else' and everything is fine, but if the 'if' statement does execute, it still executes the 'else' statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); 
      int highwayNumber;
      int primaryNumber;
      int getnServed;

      highwayNumber = scnr.nextInt();
      getnServed = highwayNumber % 100;
      
      if (highwayNumber < 1)
         System.out.println(highwayNumber + " is not a valid interstate highway number.");
      
      if (highwayNumber > 999)
         System.out.println(highwayNumber + " is not a valid interstate highway number.");
         
      if (highwayNumber < 100 && highwayNumber > 0)
         if (highwayNumber % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println("I-" + highwayNumber + " is primary, going east/west.");
         else
            System.out.println("I-" + highwayNumber + " is primary, going north/south.");
      
      else
      
         if (highwayNumber > 999) 
            System.out.println(highwayNumber + " is not a valid interstate highway number.");
            
         if (highwayNumber < 100)
            System.out.println(highwayNumber + " is not a valid interstate highway number.");
            
         else
            if (highwayNumber > 99 && highwayNumber < 1000)
               if (highwayNumber % 2 == 0)
                  System.out.println("I-" + highwayNumber + " is auxiliary, serving I-" + getnServed + ", going east/west.");
               else 
                  System.out.println("I-" + highwayNumber + " is auxiliary, serving I-" + getnServed + ", going north/south.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Put appropriate `{` and `}` around every if and else block. The compiler doesn't consider your indentation, so it won't be able to decipher what you mean when you have nested ifs and elses without braces.

Comment: The brackets need to surround ALL the code you want to execute if the condition is true (for if), or not true (for else)

Comment: Can you show us how you think they should go? Then we can explain why the compiler gets angry

Comment: In case the earlier comments don't make it clear...the way you have your code indented is NOT how the compiler will actually interpret your logic.  If you think the indentation matches the logic, then that's probably where you are getting messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not very clearly expressed, and braces should always be used - even when they are optional. Additionally, you are using a lot of `if`(s) without matching `else if`(s) in chains here. I tried to clean it up.

```
if (highwayNumber < 1) {
    System.out.println(highwayNumber + " is not a valid interstate highway number.");
} else if (highwayNumber > 999) {
    System.out.println(highwayNumber + " is not a valid interstate highway number.");
} else if (highwayNumber < 100 && highwayNumber > 0) {
    if (highwayNumber % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("I-" + highwayNumber + " is primary, going east/west.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("I-" + highwayNumber + " is primary, going north/south.");
    }
} else {
    if (highwayNumber > 999) {
        System.out.println(highwayNumber + " is not a valid interstate highway number.");
    } else if (highwayNumber < 100) {
        System.out.println(highwayNumber + " is not a valid interstate highway number.");
    } else if (highwayNumber > 99 && highwayNumber < 1000) {
        if (highwayNumber % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(
                    "I-" + highwayNumber + " is auxiliary, serving I-"
                    + getnServed + ", going east/west.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                    "I-" + highwayNumber + " is auxiliary, serving I-"
                    + getnServed + ", going north/south.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is also probably worth noting that some of these are dead branches (i.e. the second > 999)

Comment: Still half asleep but that whole second `else` looks redundant